How do i make Pitest work with a multi-module project with cucumber tests that are in a separate module
I have this approximate project structure:
project/
├── module-with-java-code/
│   ├── main
│   ├── test
│   └── build.gradle
├── module-with-cucumber-features/
│   ├── features [test]/
│   │   ├── feature-test-folder-1/
│   │   │   ├── test-1.feature
│   │   │   └── -...
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── test/
│   │   ├── glue/
│   │   │   └── glues...
│   │   ├── TestNgCucumberTest for feature-test-folder-1
│   │   └── ...
│   └── build.gradle
├── way more more modules...
└── build.gradle

I want to execute Pitest on code in module-with-java-code but i want to run it with tests inside its own module and the feature tests from module-with-cucumber-features.
The versions i am using:

gradle: 8.11.1
pitest-gradle-plugin: 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.15.0'
pitest-testng-plugin: 'org.pitest:pitest-testng-plugin:1.0.0'
pitest-junit5-plugin: 'org.pitest:pitest-junit5-plugin:1.2.1'
cucumber

'io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.6',
'io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:7.20.1',
'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.20.1',
'io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:7.20.1',
'me.jvt.cucumber:reporting-plugin:7.11.0'



I have tried to follow the documentation on gradle-pitest-plugin together with the multi-module example
What i was expecting was that it would recognize the cucumber tests (e.g. TestNgCucumberTest) and for each mutation execute the cucumber tests and the unit tests.
However i am running into some problems with the configuration:
I tried to configure it in the module-with-cucumber-features
Here it give an error: No mutations found
configure(project(':module-with-cucumber-features')) {
    apply plugin: 'info.solidsoft.pitest'
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':module-with-java-code')
    }

    configurations { mutableCodeBase { transitive false } }
    dependencies { mutableCodeBase project(':module-with-java-code') }
    pitest {
        mutators = ["ALL"]
        mainSourceSets = [project(':module-with-java-code').sourceSets.main]
        testSourceSets = [sourceSets.test]
        targetTests = ['com.example.TestNgCucumberTest']
        additionalMutableCodePaths = [configurations.mutableCodeBase.singleFile]
    }
}

I tried to configure it in the root project
Here it give an error: "Could not get unknown property 'implementation' for configuration container for project ':module-with-java-code' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer"
configure(project(':module-with-cucumber-features')) {
    apply plugin: 'info.solidsoft.pitest'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':module-with-java-code')
    }

    //Additional configuration to resolve :module-with-java-code project JAR as mutable code path for PIT
    configurations {
        mutableCodeBase { transitive false }
        dependencies {
            mutableCodeBase.extendsFrom(project(':module-with-java-code').configurations.implementation)
        }
    }
    pitest {
        timestampedReports = false
        mainSourceSets = [project.sourceSets.main, project(':module-with-java-code').sourceSets.main]
        //Generates deprecation warning in Gradle 5.6+
        //Asked for recommendation: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/accessing-other-module-dependency-files-without-mutable-project-state-warnings/35048
        additionalMutableCodePaths = configurations.mutableCodeBase.files
//        additionalMutableCodePaths = project(':module-with-java-code').jar.outputs.files.getFiles()  //Workaround
    }
}


Your additionalMutableCodePaths looks different from the documentation here https://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/

Unrelated to your problem, you don't need io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.6
